# Java, Array of Objects

Tags: java

This is a trivial question, but my Java is rusty and it's got me stumped; I am getting a null-pointer exception.   It may be obvious what I am trying to do based on the code below - but I will explain...

I need an array of objects and I don't want to create another file. For this trivial project, I do not want getters and setters.  I have seen an example similar to below that uses a linked list based on a class that is located inside of another class. But, I am more proficient with arrays than linked lists, so I want to use arrays.

```
public class Ztest {

    Stuff[] st = new Stuff[2];

    public Ztest(){

    }

    class Stuff{
        public String x;
        public boolean y;
        public Stuff(){}
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Ztest test = new Ztest();

        test.st[0].x = "hello";
        test.st[0].y = true;        
        test.st[1].x = "world";
        test.st[1].y = false;       

        System.out.println(test.st[0].x);
        System.out.println(test.st[0].y);
        System.out.println(test.st[1].x);
        System.out.println(test.st[1].y);       
    }
}
```

Comment: all you told what you **did not** want. tell us some what you want.

Comment: Sorry whats the actual question?

Comment: Unless this is homework I would just use LinkedList.

Comment: You might want to look at your array again, you forgot to initialise the array correctly. This would NPE.

Comment: Nishant, Joey & Joey: You are right (I goofed). I just edited the question with the null pointer exception I was getting.  I'm new around here... would it be good practice to copy/paste the entire working script below the solution I picked as correct into a comment... or is that a bad idea. (I'm thinking it could be useful to someone).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign a value to `st[0]` and `st[1]` first:

```
test.st[0] = new Stuff();
test.st[1] = new Stuff();
```

Comment: Can you help me here..I want to know why we need to initialize all the components separately when we have already created the array..

Comment: Logan: Creating the array does nothing more than reserve space for objects. It does *not* create the objects themselves. This is different from primitive types (`int`, `double`, etc.) which have some kind of value (which is them initialized to `0`). But every object you want to exist you have to create explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Joey. I have another doubt. Now when we have already allocated memory for the array, and are creating objects corresponding to each entry in the array, whether the newly created object use the memory associated with the array only or new memory will be allocated to them and then the new objects will be referenced from their corresponding entries in the array?

Comment: The array only holds references, the actual memory used for the objects is elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Java allocates null for object values in new arrays.  You'll need something like `test.st[0] = new Stuff()` before using it.

Answer (score 2):

You need `test.st[0]=new Stuff();` etc. since `Stuff[] st = new Stuff[2];` creates an array but the elements (references) are still null.

In terms of C/C++ this would be `Stuff** st = new Stuff*[2];`, i.e. the st is an array of pointers to `Stuff` instances, whereas the pointers still point to nothing yet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put an instance of Stuff into test.st[0] and test.st[1].

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you want to use a list.

```
static class Stuff {
    public String x;
    public boolean y;

    // generated by my IDE.
    Stuff(String x, boolean y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    // generated by my IDE.
    public String toString() {
        return "Stuff{" + "x='" + x + '\'' + ", y=" + y + '}';
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<Stuff> list = new ArrayList<Stuff>();

    list.add(new Stuff("hello", true));
    list.add(new Stuff("world", false));

    System.out.println(list);
}
```

prints

```
[Stuff{x='hello', y=true}, Stuff{x='world', y=false}]
```